# Reading CSV file having Field name in each line?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am working in an ERP integration software. I need to parse CSV file from HRM application to make an entry.
I am getting the input CSV file like this:

> $Emp.No$=123456,$CardNo$=254658,$InTime$="12/11/2013 09:03:05",$OutTime$="12/11/2013 17:25:20"
>   $Emp.No$=565556,$CardNo$=254689,$InTime$="12/11/2013 09:03:50",$OutTime$="12/11/2013 18:01:11"

The CSV file doesn't have a column name header, instead each field has a field name associated with it inside `$FieldName$`.

I tried to parse it with [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). It just works fine, when using `ReadFieldsByIndex()` method.

**Problem:**
Some of the columns do not have `$InTime$` or `$OutTime$`. So, reading by index fails. How can I read only available data and how to map according to the field name available in each line.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't got a CSV file there. You have a data file, each line of which contains one or more key/value pairs, separated by commas. The key and value are separated by an `=` and the key is enclosed by `$`'s.

Having expressed what you have, that should help you identify a solution:

1. Don't use a CSV framework.
2. Read each line at a time from the file.
3. Split the line on `,` to give you the key value pairs.
4. Split the key value pairs on `=` to give the two parts.
5. (Optionally) remove the `$` from the key name.

You then should have a suitable level of data to transfer these values into whatever destination objects you have.

Answer (score 0):

This will write to the separate file with headers and followed by values.

```
        string file =@"D:\STACKOVERFLOW\csvproblem.txt";            
        string newfile =@"D:\STACKOVERFLOW\output.txt";

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newfile);


        try{
            string header = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb_header = new StringBuilder();
            bool recordHeader = true;

            while(sr.EndOfStream==false){
                string readLine = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] split = readLine.Split(',');
                sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (string str in split)
                {
                    if (recordHeader)
                    {
                        if (str.IndexOf('$') < str.LastIndexOf('$'))
                        {
                           sb_header.AppendFormat("{0},",
                               str.Substring(str.IndexOf('$'),str.IndexOf('$')+str.LastIndexOf('$')+1));
                        }
                    }

                    sb.AppendFormat("{0},", str.Substring(str.IndexOf('=')+1));
                }

                if (recordHeader)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(sb_header.ToString().Trim(','));
                }
                sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString().Trim(','));

                recordHeader = false;
            }
        }
        finally{
            sr.Close();
            sw.Close();
        }
```